# Lua While Loops Error. Why is my while loop Malfunctioning?

Tags: lua

As a new lua programmer i am enjoying learning new things in lua. I am learning from:  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/lua/lua_loops.htm
However, when i practice my code it wont work. In my code i defined a object called "FolderImBalanced" and make that object to TRUE. Later on in the code i changed the object to FALSE. But the code is not working. How come? 
PLEASE NOTE: i have some "code" things in messages, so the code in the message is not REAL code. Its just a message, i was practicing using messages at the moment.

```
 --[[Inset Nil.Lua("ServerStorage")]]--
GetServerStats,UserImbalance = "Lua Server Status","Inbalance Pulsle"
print(UserImbalance)
--[[Do:Value=="Nil" Function Ontouched.]]--
FolderImBalanced,NewNilValue = true,false
while (true)
do
FolderImBalanced = false
end
print(FolderImBalanced)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you written is working, even though it may not do what you expect it to do. Right now, your `while` loop is executed indefinitely, as you set the loop condition to `true` (so it will always execute the loop body) and don't have any exits from the loop using `break` statements. Since the loop continues to execute indefinitely, the script will have to be aborted, as it will never exit the loop.

Comment: If its a while loop it should repeat the code over  and over again. So should'nt  FolderImBalanced be placed true, if the code is repeating over and over again?